# Why my combobox only shows one item? c# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mil4u.png)I'm trying to show all my items on a combobox, but when y run my app I only get one item. Can you help me please, here's my code

```
try
{
   MySqlConnection conection = new MySqlConnection("server = 127.0.0.1; database = sistemalaboratorio; Uid = root; pwd =;");
   string selectQuery = "SELECT clavemateria FROM materia";
   conection.Open();
   MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(selectQuery, conection);
   MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();                    

   while (reader.Read());
   {                      
       comboBox1.Items.Add(reader["clavemateria"].ToString());
   }
} catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: What is the result of you query?

Comment: I only get the last result of my Query.

Comment: try running it with `SELECT COUNT(*) clavemateria FROM materia` instead

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work :(

Comment: I think you will need to try and debug this to find out what is happening during the while loop. You can add a breakpoint to your code see what is actually happening. It may be the bug is in a different part of your code that you have not posted. Also I presume you have actually clicked the combobox to see that there is only one item?

Comment: Yes, I click on the combobox and I only get one item. I already search for a bug in my code, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this read is happening before the page loads the combobox, make sure your *materia* table has more than 1 record in it.

These queries might usful to count the records in your SQL table in case you dont have direct access using SQL Management studio

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM materia WITH (NOLOCK)
```

-- NOLOCK here is for testing for this answer: no more, no less

or

```
SELECT clavemateria, count(*)
FROM materia
GROUP BY clavemateria
```

Also you can try this:

```
string qr1 = "select * from materia ";
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qr1, con);
con.Open();
SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader(); 
cmbcat.Items.Clear(); 
while (dr1.Read()) 
{
 cmbcat.Items.Add(new Item(dr1["clavemateria"].ToString(), dr1["clavemateria"].ToString())); 
}
 con.Close();
```

Or refer to this example

Comment: No, it's not working. I'm still getting only my last item. I have 4 items on materia, and I only get the last one.

Comment: So this query SELECT COUNT(*) FROM materia returns a count of 4 ?

Comment: Yes, it only returns 4

Comment: What type is comboBox1.Item? Usually they might take Text Value and a Value for the item. Is it stock HTML combobox ? Also make sure you close the reader after your loop. Can you debug and step in into while loop ? Try this: `string qr1 = "select * from materia ";
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(qr1, con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        cmbcat.Items.Clear();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            cmbcat.Items.Add(new Item(dr1["clavemateria"].ToString(), dr1["clavemateria"].ToString()));

        }
        con.Close();`

Comment: I'm still getting the last item only. The combobox I'm using is from Visual Studio.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/685782/to-add-combo-box-items-from-Sql-DB-in-csharp-net) example for further troubleshooting. Id personally create a list or an array just to make sure your reader is getting out 4 records. If it is, then its the way youre adding items to the combobox. Try creating a new Item() {text member, value member}

Comment: No, I couldn't solve it. I still get only one item in my combobox.

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit more in order for the community to help you. Have you stepped into the loop and try to inspect the results there ? Can you see 4 result objects in your reader object ? Did you try running the example code above ?

Comment: Yes, I already use the example code. But i get an error on the cmbcat.Items.Add(new Item(dr1["clavemateria"].ToString(), dr1["clavemateria"].ToString())); cmbcat is my combobox?